# Efficient way to search for an element in an array based on its property?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, search

I have three variables, `a`, `b` and `c`. Each of these variables have a property  `foo` which if is a `Boolean`.

Out of `a`, `b` and `c`, exactly two of them have their `foo` property set to `true`.

What's the most efficient way to find out which one has it set to `false`?

To put this into context, I have a function that I want to do some stuff based on which variable has `foo` set to `false`, and I am not sure what's the best way to go about determining what the `false` variable is.

E.g. I could manually check using if statements like so:

```
function doThings():void
    {
        if (a.foo == true)
        {
            if (b.foo == true)
            {
                True = a;
                True2 = b;
                False = c;
            }
            else
            {
                True = a;
                True2 = c;
                False = b;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            True = b;
            True2 = c;
            False = a;
        }

        //More things...
    }
```

Or another way I thought of was to pass the two variables that I know have `foo` set to true as arguments to the function, then do this:

```
function doThings(para, para2):void
    {
        if (a != para && a != para2)
        {
            False = a;
        }
        else if (b != para && b != para2)
        {
            False = b;
        }
        else
        {
            False = c;
        }

        //More things...
    }
```

Side note: The two that have `foo` set to true are `push`ed into an array at runtime so I can't tell exactly which one is which programmatically, but I CAN pass them as arguments to the function(s).

Knowing this, I could also just as easily check which one isn't in the array using `indexOf`, but the fundamentals of the method would still remain the same.

This could be done like so, without using parameters:

```
function doThings():void
    {
        if (TrueArray.indexOf(a) == -1)
        {
            False = a;
            True = b;
            True2 = c;
        }
        else if (TrueArray.indexOf(b) == -1)
        {
            False = b;
            True = c;
            True2 = a;
        }
        else
        {
            False = c;
            True = a;
            True2 = b;
        }

        //More things...
    }
```

As it stands, the second method looks more appealing, and seems to be the simplest, but I'm just wondering if there are more sophisticated ways of doing this.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your second option is the right direction. I would probably implement it like this:

```
function findFalseFoo(...objects:Array):Object {
    for each (var object:Object in objects) {
        if (object.foo == false)
            return object;
    }
}

function doStuff():void {
    var falseFoo:Object = findFalseFoo(a, b, c);
    switch (falseFoo) {
        case a:
            // do stuff
            break;
        case b:
            // do stuff
            break;
        case c:
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Of course, in the code you've posted all you're doing in each case is setting the `False`, `True`, and `True2` properties. In that case you could just do this:

```
function assignTrueFalse(...objects:Array):void {
    False = True = True1 = null;
    for each (var object:Object in objects) {
        if (object.foo) {
            if (True == null) 
                True = object;
            else
                True2 = object;
        } else {
            False = object;
        }
    }
}

assignTrueFalse(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first item in the array with a `foo` value of false, then the most efficient way would likely be a simple for loop.  This would also scale automatically to any number of items in your array (instead of hard coded to 3 items)

```
//assumes you have an array of objects called 'myArray'

function getFirstFalseFoo():Object {
    //iterate over every item in 'myArray'
    for(var i:int = 0, len:int = myArray.length; i < len; i++){
        //if the array item's foo value is false, return that object (thus exiting the loop)
        if(!myArray[i].foo){
            return myArray[i];
        }
    }
}

var myFalseFoo:Object = getFirstFalseFoo();


//OR, you could pass in objects as parameters to the function like this:
function getFirstFalseFoo(... args):Object {
    //iterate over every item passed to the function
    for(var i:int = 0, len:int = args.length; i < len; i++){
        //if the item has a foo property and it's false, return that object (thus exiting the loop)
        if(args[i].hasOwnProperty("foo") && !args[i].foo){
            return args[i];
        }
    }
}

var myFalseFoo:Object = getFirstFalseFoo(a, b, c);  //you could pass as many objects as you want
```

Of course there are lots of ways to accomplish this and the most "efficient" can depend on a lot of factors and is subject to your definition of efficiency (computationally fastest, least amount of code, best scaleability etc).

---

As an aside, best practice in AS3 (and many other languages) is have variable and function names start with lower case letters. Also best not to have variable names match language keywords. I'd recommend changing your variables to something along these lines to make it easier to read and understand:

```
var falseObj:Object;
var trueObj:Object;
var true2Obj:Object;
```

Comment: So... should I delete my answer now that you've edited in all my code into your answer? :)

Comment: Funny, I was going to say thing when your answer came in.

Comment: [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36457874/3) and [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36457874/4) after my answer with pretty much the same code... but whatever, maybe just a coincidence, it's certainly not a novel solution.

Comment: I upvoted your answer anyway since it covers more, cheers. :)

Comment: The first of the linked edits (edit 3) was 10 minutes prior to your answer if you look at the time stamps.  At any rate, I rolled back the later edit I made after your answer came as it is indeed quite similar and redundant.

Comment: Well, you're right... sorry for the fuss. You really don't need to roll back your edit. :)

Comment: It's not really important.  All that matters is that the info is on this page somewhere.